# EasyMock : mocking the new operation possible?

Tags: java, mocking, easymock

Is it possible to do something like that with EasyMock:

```
class ClassName{
   void method(){
      TypeToMock a = new TypeToMock();
   }
}
```

and I want to mock `TypeToMock` without passing it as a value to class `ClassName`. Is it possible?  If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think this is possible.

If you want to mock out a dependency then you have to inject that dependency into the class under test, either through the constructor, through a setter method or directly into the method you want to test as an argument.

If your class is creating this using `new` and only doing it once then you should inject the dependency using the method that gives you best match of scope.

If your class is creating an object using `new` several times, then you could inject a factory which produces the objects instances instead.  then you can provide a mock factory which produces mock instances.